# How to use twitter factory from twitter widgets.js

Tags: javascript, twitter

I've got a problem with loading twitter button via twitter factory. I've included library immediately after  start

```
<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      t = window.twttr || {};
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

    t._e = [];
    t.ready = function(f) {
      t._e.push(f);
    };

    return t;
  }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>
```

then I've create this html tag in my pop-up (fixed position element, not displayed at the page load)

```
<div id="tweet-container"></div>
```

and finaly in my javascript file, I call the functions:

```
twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
  "https:\/\/dev.twitter.com\/web\/tweet-button",
  document.getElementById("tweet-container"),
  {
    size: "default",
    via: "twitterdev",
    related: "twitterapi,twitter",
    text: "Nový rekord!",
    hashtags: "drakiada,hra"
  }
);
twttr.widgets.load();
```

But the button is not loading, whats wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably trying to execute something on the object before the js has loaded because it is asynchronous. Put this into your ready function (if using Jquery) so that when it's loaded you can then use it

```
twttr.ready(
  function (twttr) {
    // bind events here
  }
);
```